# boolean comparison against variable returns error

Tags: karate

In trying to compare a boolean response object to a boolean variable, I am running into issues.  Should the following work as a basic comparison, or should boolean values be compared in a different method?

I have the following response

```
{
  "data": {
    "updateNetworkSecurity": {
      "enabled": true
    }
  }
```

However, when comparing the enabled flag to a variable set as a boolean of true, you can see that the comparison fails because it believes the value is an array or list, although there are no brackets around either value and the values of both are BOOLEAN, as shown in the type comparison at the end of the error.

```
match failed: EACH_EQUALS
  $ | actual is not an array or list (BOOLEAN:BOOLEAN)
  true
  true
```

Here is the variable assignment
    `* def securityStatusInput = true`

Here is the match call
      `* match $.data.updateNetworkSecurity.enabled == securityStatusInput`

Some simple troubleshooting to address the list/array issue:

If I set the match to `* match $.data.updateNetworkSecurity[0].enabled == securityStatusInput`, I get the following error:

```
match failed: EQUALS
  $ | actual path does not exist (STRING:BOOLEAN)
  '#notpresent'
  true
```

Setting the above to a wildcard value, `* match $.data.updateNetworkSecurity[*].enabled == securityStatusInput`, also fails:

```
match failed: EQUALS
  $ | data types don't match (LIST:BOOLEAN)
  []
  true
```

Comment: If the values for comparison are false, assertions pass, but unsure if that is based on a true evaluation, due to the above.

Comment: I don't understand this statement at all, sorry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Works fine for me:

```
* def response = 
"""
{
  data: {
    updateNetworkSecurity: {
      enabled: true
    }
  }
}
"""
* match response.data.updateNetworkSecurity.enabled == true
```

Most likely you have a mistake with the nesting of your objects. One tip - the moment you use wildcards, you always end up with an array, so watch out for that. Avoid wildcards if you are going for simple matches. Teams typically never run into problems like you describe because you are encouraged to match chunks of JSON at a time instead of one primitive value at a time.

Using a variable ? That should work as well:

```
* def securityStatusInput = true    
* def response = {"data":{"updateNetworkSecurity":{"enabled":true}}}
* match response.data.updateNetworkSecurity.enabled == securityStatusInput
```

Comment: I must have had a special character in one of the lines, as a complete rewrite of the test now works.  Thank you for the verification.